# Too many network interfaces in wsl ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I entered the command `ip addr`, the output is as follows:

```
8: eth0: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 50:5b:c2:cc:e0:98
    inet 169.254.33.236/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::df89:be11:e274:94b/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: eth1: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 8c:16:45:8b:9c:2b
    inet 169.254.11.212/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d07f:1979:9884:13/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01
    inet 192.168.195.1/24 brd 192.168.195.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 997sec preferred_lft 997sec
    inet6 fe80::26b0:b807:cb38:7dca/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08
    inet 192.168.58.1/24 brd 192.168.58.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 997sec preferred_lft 997sec
    inet6 fe80::152e:2cf3:7f6b:c38f/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: eth4: <> mtu 1400 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:ff:7e:64:00:4f
    inet 169.254.6.152/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b8:8bce:e70f:ba85/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:17
    inet 192.168.56.1/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e:1433:1cda:acf0/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:05
    inet 192.168.138.1/24 brd 192.168.138.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c505:d240:9154:33e9/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
70: eth7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:15:5d:bd:fe:95
    inet 172.25.224.1/20 brd 172.25.239.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8222:b798:2151:1d80/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: eth8: <> mtu 65535 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 169.254.82.130/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f6a:cae0:bef2:2167/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: eth9: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:ff:b7:d8:7d:d5
    inet 169.254.198.16/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6e45:395:ea72:356b/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: eth10: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 169.254.143.212/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be4c:f7aa:1557:3605/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
20: wifi0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ieee802.11 50:5b:c2:cc:e0:97
    inet 192.168.31.204/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 41495sec preferred_lft 41495sec
    inet6 fe80::dbf4:e22c:fc70:d83c/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
25: wifi1: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ieee802.11 52:5b:c2:cc:e0:97
    inet 169.254.164.175/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cb7e:8732:90fd:6c51/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: wifi2: <> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ieee802.11 62:5b:c2:cc:e0:97
    inet 169.254.133.94/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e58c:c9c2:62d1:dc62/64 scope link dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I don't know why there are so many network interfaces. And I tried google, but none of them answer my question. My system information is `Linux DESKTOP-D1D9HKQ 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #3393-Microsoft Mon Aug 14 14:52:00 PST 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. I want to know how these network interfaces is created and what's the purpose of the wifi interface.

I'm not very good at networking stuff but this seems strange to me due to the fact that I never saw this many network interfaces before. Is this normal or could this be something bad? What can I do about it if it is something bad?